# How to delete data in bulk with multiple conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am looking for a SQL query where I have to delete data from a table based on combination of 2 conditions.

I have a table `dbo.ABC` from which I have to delete the rows if combination of values passed as input is present in column A and column B.

Table - ABC

```
column A   column B
===========================
100           US
200           IND
```

Now I have to delete record if column A is 100 and column B is US. But I want to pass multiple inputs like 100 and 200 as column A and US and IND as column B respectively. 100 and US will be the one combination to delete 1st record and 200 and IND will be the another combination to delete 2nd record. Similarly I want to pass list of 1000 inputs like this way to delete 1000 records in single shot rather than calling it 1000 times with single combination.

Can I use multiple IN statement to delete the data as I have to pass list of combination of `column_A` and `column_B`?

How to use for-loop to delete the data if I pass list of combination of `column_A` and `column_B`?

I am new to this field so not have much knowledge.

Your help will be appreciated..

Thank you.

Comment: Table Valued Parameter or Table Variable is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Some less performant but easy to use method(as index will not be used) is to use the `concat` as follows:

```
delete from your_Table t
 where concat(t.column1,'##@@##',column2) in ('100##@@##US', '200##@@##IND')
```

I have used `##@@##` as separtor. You can use any value which you think is not allowed in `column1` and `column2`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the most straight forward method using tuples with `IN` isn't supported.

Now the most obvious method would be to simply use `AND` and `OR`.

```
DELETE FROM abc
            WHERE column_a = 100
                  AND column_b = 'US'
                   OR column_a = 200
                      AND column_b = 'IN';
```

But that's also a bit messy.

A relatively clean variant would be to use a table variable, fill it with the targeted combinations and do a `DELETE ... JOIN ...`.

```
DECLARE @targets
        TABLE (column_a integer,
               column_b char(2));

INSERT INTO @targets
            (column_a,
             column_b)
            VALUES (100,
                    'US'),
                   (200,
                    'IN');

DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN @targets t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

A variant of this uses a temporary table instead of a table variable.

```
CREATE TABLE #targets
             (column_a integer,
              column_b char(2));

INSERT INTO #targets
            (column_a,
             column_b)
            VALUES (100,
                    'US'),
                   (200,
                    'IN');

DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN #targets t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

Instead of filling a table variable or a temporary table before hand, the values can also be defined inline.

Additionally a CTE can be used to separate the definition of the targte values somewhat from it's later use.

To define the values a `SELECT ... FROM` a `VALUES` clause is pretty neat.

```
WITH targets
AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM (VALUES (100,
                     'US'),
                    (200,
                     'IN')) v (column_a,
                               column_b)
)
DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN targets t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

Instead of the `SELECT ... FROM` the `VALUES` clause, multiple `FROM`-less `SELECT`s with `UNION ALL` can be used too.

```
WITH targets
AS
(
SELECT 100 column_a,
       'US' column_b
       UNION ALL
SELECT 200 column_a,
      'IN' column_b
)
DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN targets t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

Instead of CTEs an inline derived table is also possible.

Again this can use a `SELECT ... FROM` a `VALUES` clause to define the target values.

```
DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                               FROM (VALUES (100,
                                             'US'),
                                            (200,
                                             'IN')) v (column_a,
                                                       column_b)) t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

Or it can use multiple `FROM`-less `SELECT`s with `UNION ALL`.

```
DELETE a
       FROM abc a
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 100 column_a,
                               'US' column_b
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 200 column_a,
                               'IN' column_b) t
                       ON t.column_a = a.column_a
                          AND t.column_b = a.column_b;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=89324c71a115e09b09e9030247ce7881)